# Ordering .each results in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if it is possible to dictate the order (i.e. :order => 'created_at DESC') within the view. I realize that logic in the view is not ideal but I seem to be having some problems locating where to affect this output.

For instance, here is my code:

```
<% @user.questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= link_to_unless_current h (question.title), question %>
   Created about <%= time_ago_in_words h(question.created_at) %> ago
   Updated about <%= time_ago_in_words h(question.updated_at) %> ago

   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(question) %> | 
   <%= link_to 'Destroy', question, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>

<% end %>
```

In my QuestionsController I have the following index action but it is not affecting the output from the code above.

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController 

def index

    @questions = Question.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @questions }
    end
  end

end
```

UPDATE: With respect to changing the @user.questions to @questions I get this error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

UPDATE 2: I guess I should mention that this code is in the questions show view. `views/questions/show.html.erb.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
<% unless @questions.empty? %>
   <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      # ...
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in your view and

```
@questions = Question.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 20)
```

inside `show` or `index` method of `QuestionsController`.

Comment: That is not the actual syntax for the view right? It needs the <% doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to do it is to use `reverse_each` instead of `each`:

```
<% @user.questions.reverse_each do |question| %>
```

You get your questions in the descending order, and don't touch anything in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
```

instead of

```
<% @user.questions.each do |question| %>
```

EDITED. You can avoid nil error by using one of the following ways.

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>


<% end unless @questions.blank?  %>
```

OR

```
<% for question in @questions %>


<% end unless @questions.blank?  %>
```

Comment: Nice...that did get rid of the error but it is not pulling in the user's questions now. How do I send :user with the request?

Comment: how would i do this in haml, as I omit the end tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable `@questions` instead of `@user.questions` in your view.